# How can I get Task.ContinueWith to execute async methods in sequence?

Tags: c#, task

Given the following code, I would expect the actions to be executed sequentially

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp32
{
    class Program
    {
        static SpinLock Lock = new SpinLock();
        static Task Head = Task.CompletedTask;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            CreateTask(1);
            CreateTask(2);
            CreateTask(3);
            CreateTask(4);
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Half way through executing
            CreateTask(5);
            CreateTask(6);
            CreateTask(7);
            CreateTask(8);
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }

        static void CreateTask(int i)
        {
            bool lockTaken = false;
            while (!lockTaken)
                Lock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
            try
            {
                Head = Head.ContinueWith(_ => DoActionAsync(i));
            }
            finally
            {
                Lock.Exit();
            }
        }

        static async Task DoActionAsync(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ": Creating " + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ": Finished " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

But the actual output is

```
Hello World!
09:08:06: Creating 1
09:08:06: Creating 2
09:08:06: Creating 3
09:08:06: Creating 4
09:08:07: Finished 2
09:08:07: Finished 3
09:08:07: Finished 4
09:08:07: Creating 5
09:08:07: Finished 1
09:08:07: Creating 6
09:08:07: Creating 7
09:08:07: Creating 8
09:08:08: Finished 7
09:08:08: Finished 6
09:08:08: Finished 8
09:08:08: Finished 5
```

Why is 2 finishing before 1 rather than not starting until after 1 has completed? (I expect this is the same cause as them all finishing at the same time).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accuracy of Task.Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742521/accuracy-of-task-delay)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `ContinueWith` rather than `await`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay No, the Task.Delay is just to make it noticeable by humans. ContinueWith is what should be executing in sequence, not the delay.

Comment: @mjwills I want to fire and forget calls to a network resource that I want to ensure never occur out of sequence nor get executed at the same time. This is a single-threaded app (Blazor WASM).

Comment: Does `Head = Head.ContinueWith(async _ => await DoActionAsync(i));` work?

Comment: You're continuations are calling `DoActionAsync` and are completing when that method returns - not when the `Task` that it returns has completed. You've got too many layers of tasks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Have you tested this hypothesis?

Comment: @PeterMorris Damien is correct - your output proves it.

Comment: Can you talk us through whether https://dotnetfiddle.net/V4GiEs might be an option? Its much simpler in my mind.

Comment: @PeterMorris - Remove the `async` from `DoActionAsync` and it will work fine. Damien is correct.

Comment: @PeterMorris "_ContinueWith is what should be executing in sequence_" But they do. Look at your "Creating" statements; they are all sequential. It's the call to `Task.Delay` inside `DoActionAsync` that's causing the differences with your "Finished" statements.

Comment: @mjwills I need fire and forget in a guaranteed sequence, where I can add new tasks at any point (whilst executing, or hours later)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I want the next task to start only when the previous one has completely finished (creating + await + finished)

Comment: Would creating your own extension to sequence tasks provide the functionality you're looking for? https://dotnetfiddle.net/5EculP (something like this). Though keep in mind that in this example if one of the tasks crashes the whole chain crashes

Comment: @Knoop That does exactly what I am trying to achieve, please add it as an answer. I still don't understand my problem though, I thought that is exactly what ContinueWith does.

Comment: Yeah did not add it as an answer since it doesn't answer the question asked: why `ContinueWith` behaves as it does (and tbh there is a lot of complexity under the hood that I don't understand). But enjoy the solution and good luck on your project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the tasks are nested. You are creating tasks within tasks without unwrapping them.

try this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp32
{
    class Program
    {
        static SpinLock Lock = new SpinLock();
        static Task Head = Task.CompletedTask;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            CreateTask(1);
            CreateTask(2);
            CreateTask(3);
            CreateTask(4);
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Half way through executing
            CreateTask(5);
            CreateTask(6);
            CreateTask(7);
            CreateTask(8);
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }

        static void CreateTask(int i)
        {
            bool lockTaken = false;
            while (!lockTaken)
                Lock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
            try
            {
                Head = Head.ContinueWith(_ => DoActionAsync(i)).Unwrap();
            }
            finally
            {
                Lock.Exit();
            }
        }

        static async Task DoActionAsync(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ": Creating " + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ": Finished " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

note the `Unwrap()`
The overload you are "abusing" is the general `Func<object, T>` one where you assign Task to type T instead of a result type. Normally `ContinueWith` uses a synchronous delegate.
.NET thought about this and they have created `Unwrap()`, which unwraps the nested task.

Answer (score 2):

`.ContinueWith(_ => DoActionAsync(i))` Returns a `Task` (or specifically a `Task<Task>`) that completes when `DoActionAsync` returns. DoActionAsync will return at the first await, thus completing the outer `Task` and allowing the next operation to begin.

So it will run each "create" serially, but "Finished" will run asynchronously.

A simple solution would be to schedule all the tasks using a [LimitedconcurrencyTaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netcore-3.1) instead. Or just create a queue of the operations and have a thread processing the queue in order.