# Trouble implementing delay in C# method with return type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

I need help in adding a delay in this methods.

```
public string DoSomething(ref GameData data, bool isActive)
{
   return AnimationManager.CreateAnimation(data);
}
```

In the AnimationManager

```
public class AnimationManager
{
    public static string CreateAnimation(GameData data)
    {
        Sword newSword = new Sword(data.SwordData);
        string returnString = newSword.GetSwordString();
        
        AnimateSwords(data.SwordData, data.SwordObjects, returnString);
    }

    public static void AnimateSwords(SwordData data, List<Swords> swordObjects, string returnString)
    {
         //DO ANIMATION HERE, BUT DELAY FIRST
    }
}
```

The goal is to delay the animation after 1 second. Any help is appreciated. TYIA!

I cannot do IEnumerator becuase the class is not in MonoBehaviour. I tried async but I can't make it to work.

EDIT:
Sorry I didn't elaborate on the issue. CreateAnimation is called from DoSomething(ref GameData data, bool isActive). I canot convert this to async Task becuase it has a ref in it's parameter.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(1000)` ?

Comment: I cannot convert the first method "CreateAnimation" to a async Task<string> because the code that's calling it is using ref in it's parameter, so I cannot convert that to a Task as well.

Comment: Modify that code too. You can't have asynchronous code without tasks. If you have to run in a specific platform, eg Android or iOS, make it explicit in both the tags and question. Mobile platforms have their own ways of delaying

Comment: Besides, animations never depend on application timers because there's no guarantee they'll fire at a specific moment. WPF, Unity, Android, iOS, UWP - any UI stack that has animations, has specific support for displaying specific frames and transitions, using highly accurate OS-level timers

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing delays etc manually? I would assume that Unity3D have a fairly competent animation system.

Comment: MonoBehavior's [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) allows you to call a method after a delay. The doc page explains that if you want to pass data you should use [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html) instead

Comment: I guess coroutine is the way to go. I just have to modify a whole lot of logic to implement that. thanks!

Comment: No general-purpose timer is accurate enough to provide smooth animations. Games and any application that needs animations stopped using them for this 30+ years ago, when first Windows provided the DirectX API and then game console and mobile OSs provided their own transition frameworks.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos So are the answers here suggesting to use Task.Delay wrong?  It [does use a general-purpose timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742521/accuracy-of-task-delay), I think.

Answer (score 0):

Add async keyword and Task return type to your method and add delay.

This is all you need to do:

```
public static async Task AnimateSwords(SwordData data, List<Swords> swordObjects, string returnString)
{
    //DO ANIMATION HERE, BUT DELAY FIRST
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: That's a bug. `async void` methods can't be awaited so whatever calls this method will exit before the delay ends. The code will end up calling disposed or invalid objects

Comment: my bad. Updated from void to Task

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is it OK now?

Answer (score 0):

You really should turn your method in async Task. I see that you have ref parameter here, which is excess, because, unless GameData is a struct, not a class, it is passed as reference even without ref keyword. So just omit ref keyword and make your methods async.
Other ways to perform delay is MonoBehaviour.Invoke or Coroutines, which are generally considered as less preferable, as they depend on MonoBehaviours, which is not always what you want.
I also suggest you take a look at UniTask or even UniRx libs, they are considerably powerful in handling your timeline and pretty easy to use once you're familiar with async/await.