# Why is this timer / stopwatch off eventually after about 15 minutes, 5 second diff

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, stopwatch

I found [[this article](https://taurius.medium.com/blazor-building-a-timer-and-a-stopwatch-5aea682147aa)] that shows how to build a stopwatch / timer and after about 15 minutes there's 5 second gap between my physical timer (good battery; physical timer goes ahead 5 seconds)

```
async Task StartTimer()
{
    SetButtonState();        

    isStopWatchRunning = true;
    while (isStopWatchRunning)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if (isStopWatchRunning)
        {
            stopWatchValue = stopWatchValue.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Windows or Linux (without kernel modifications) is not a real-time operating system. You cannot expect Blazor to have a real-time performance. 5 seconds is good and expected.

Comment: +1 @maciek Also as you load the system with work the inaccuracy will increase due to the way in which the OS allocates processor time.

Comment: @ChrisBD Also C# garbage collector kicks in and all bets are off.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/performance

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `Task.Delay` is *not precise*; the actual interval resolution is about `15` ms.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_Int32_

> This method depends on the system clock. This means that the time delay will approximately equal the resolution of the system clock if the milliseconds `Delay` argument is less than the resolution of the system clock, which is approximately **15 milliseconds** on Windows systems.

(**bold** is mine, Dmitrii)

In your case you can expect up to `15 ms * 900 ~ 13.5 s` gap.

Answer (score 1):

You are not measuring and accounting for how long your other code takes to run such as the call to StateHasChanged() and it is called ~900 times in that 15 minutes. Also, Task.Delay is not guaranteed to be accurate as stated in the responses to the StackOverflow question about its accuracy in the link below; which also has some possible solutions.

[Accuracy of Task.Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742521/accuracy-of-task-delay)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers do a good job of explaining *why* `Task.Delay` introduces inaccuracies when it comes to timekeeping.

An alternative approach would be to track the actual start and stop times, and then derive the elapsed time from there.

```html
<div>
    <button @onclick="@OnStart">Start</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button @onclick="@OnStop">Stop</button>
</div>
<div>
    Updating timespan: <span>@StopwatchValue</span>
</div>
<div>
    Comparing elapsed time: <span>@Elapsed</span>
</div>
```

```cs
@code {
    TimeSpan StopwatchValue { get; set; } = new();
    TimeSpan Elapsed { get; set; } = new();

    List<DateTime> StartTimes { get; } = new();
    List<DateTime> StopTimes { get; } = new();

    bool IsRunning { get; set; }

    private async Task OnStart()
    {
        if (IsRunning)
        {
            return;
        }

        IsRunning = true;

        StartTimes.Add(DateTime.Now);

        while (IsRunning)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                StopwatchValue = StopwatchValue.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                Elapsed = GetElapsedTime();
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnStop()
    {
        if (!IsRunning)
        {
            return;
        }

        StopTimes.Add(DateTime.Now);
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    private TimeSpan GetElapsedTime()
    {
        TimeSpan elapsed = new TimeSpan();

        for (int i = 0; i < StartTimes.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            DateTime start = StartTimes[i];
            DateTime stop = StopTimes[i];
            elapsed += stop - start;
        }

        elapsed += DateTime.Now - StartTimes.Last();

        return elapsed;
    }
}
```

Example fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/ko5jseqd