# System.Threading.Timer fires callback erratically

Tags: c#, timer

I wrote a class named `DoubleAnimator` that changes a double value from a start value to an end value over a period.

This class is based on a System.Threading.Timer to change and report the value.

I noticed that, mainly for first uses, the timer's callback will execute almost exactly every second instead of the asked 50 ms.

I timed the callback, to know if it took more than the interval to execute, but it takes between 0 and 3 ms.

Here is the class:

```
/// <summary>
/// DoubleAnimator animates a double value from a specified value to another one in the specified time-frame
/// </summary>
public class DoubleAnimator : IDisposable, IAnimator
{
#if DEBUG
    private readonly Logger _logger;
#endif

    private readonly double _startValue;
    private readonly double _endValue;
    private readonly TimeSpan _duration;
    private System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly double _incrementPerAnimation;
    private readonly TimeSpan _durationBetweenAnimations;

    private double _animatedValue;
    public double AnimatedValue
    {
        get { return _animatedValue; }
    }


    public DoubleAnimator(double startValue, double endValue,
                          TimeSpan duration, int numberOfAnimations)
    {
        if (numberOfAnimations <= 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Number of animation should be superior to 0");
        }
#if DEBUG
        _logger = new Logger();
#endif
        _startValue = startValue;
        _endValue = endValue;
        _duration = duration;
        _animatedValue = _startValue;
        _durationBetweenAnimations = TimeSpan.FromTicks(duration.Ticks / numberOfAnimations);
#if DEBUG
        _logger.Debug($"Duration between animations: {_durationBetweenAnimations.TotalMilliseconds}ms. Calcul: {duration.TotalMilliseconds}ms/{numberOfAnimations}");
#endif
        _incrementPerAnimation = (_endValue - _startValue) / numberOfAnimations;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (_timer != null) return;
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Animate, null, TimeSpan.Zero, _durationBetweenAnimations);
    }

    public void Abort()
    {
        if (_timer == null) return;
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void Animate(object state)
    {


#if DEBUG
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
#endif
        try
        {
#if DEBUG
            _logger.Debug("Animating...");
#endif
            _animatedValue += _incrementPerAnimation;
            bool animationFinished = false;
            if (_endValue > _startValue)
            {
                animationFinished = _animatedValue > _endValue;
            }
            else
            {
                animationFinished = _animatedValue < _endValue;
            }


            if (animationFinished)
            {
                _animatedValue = _endValue;
                _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                OnProgressChanged(_animatedValue); //Useful?
                OnCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
#if DEBUG
                _logger.Debug($"Notification of progress with value {_animatedValue}");
#endif
                OnProgressChanged(_animatedValue);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
#if DEBUG
            _logger.Debug($"Time for executing Animate: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms.");
#endif
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Completed;

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        Completed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler<ValueEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

    private void OnProgressChanged(double progress)
    {
        ValueEventArgs arg = new ValueEventArgs(progress);
        ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, arg);
    }
}
```

And an excerp of the output log file:

```
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:11.612;;Duration between animations: 50ms. Calcul: 500ms/10
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:12.215;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:12.215;;Notification of progress with value 0,1
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:12.215;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:13.214;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:13.214;;Notification of progress with value 0,2
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:13.215;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:14.213;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:14.213;;Notification of progress with value 0,3
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:14.213;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:15.213;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:15.213;;Notification of progress with value 0,4
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:15.213;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:16.215;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:16.215;;Notification of progress with value 0,5
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:16.215;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:17.215;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:17.215;;Notification of progress with value 0,6
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:17.216;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:18.215;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:18.215;;Notification of progress with value 0,7
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:18.216;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:19.215;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:19.215;;Notification of progress with value 0,8
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:19.216;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:20.213;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:20.214;;Notification of progress with value 0,9
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:20.214;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:21.214;;Animating...
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:21.214;;Notification of progress with value 1
Debug;06-02-2020 11:23:21.215;;Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
```

You can notice that the callback is executed every second, instead of every 50ms.

Could you please point me to the issue with my class?

Edit: As noted by @canton7, the issue was a threadpool starvation issue. Another object created a Thread per instance. The threadpool would take time to create a new Thread, trying to check if one completed before creating a new one.

Comment: It's usual for timers to take a bit longer than expected. It's not usual for them to take around a second longer than expected... Can you reproduce this in an isolated application? I suspect something else is going on in your application (although I'm not sure exactly what that could be)

Comment: I can't see where you are defining the duration to be 50 ms. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228313/most-accurate-timer-in-net.

Comment: I ran your code (replaced only logger implementation to the console) and nowhere near 1-second intervals, however, there is some error due to timers are not accurate. Desktops are not real-time systems. Here's the output: 
`11:44:28.022 | Duration between animations: 50ms. Calcul: 500ms/10
11:44:28.034 | Animating...
11:44:28.035 | Notification of progress with value 0.1
11:44:28.035 | Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
11:44:28.093 | Animating...
11:44:28.094 | Notification of progress with value 0.2
11:44:28.094 | Time for executing Animate: 0ms.
11:44:28.143 | Animating...`

Comment: @canton7 That's what I thought at first, but the inaccuracy seems to be of about 17 ms, versus 1000 ms in my case. I'll edit my question and try to use the object alone, without other objects handling ProgressChanged and Completed events

Comment: @nkoniishvt There might be another timer which is doing bad things for example, or your ThreadPool might be seriously starved of threads, or...

Comment: @Polyfun The interval depends on the total duration and on the number of animations (constructor parameter). In this case I put 1000 ms with 20 animations. So an animation every 50 ms. I'll make more tests and edit the question.

Comment: @yekope Thank you, this is interesting. I'll run more tests to check if I get similar results. One thing I did not precise it the compilation is made in Debug mode in Visual Studio. It may be a compilation issue. Anyway I'll run more tests and edit the question.

Comment: @canton7 Good point. Thank you, I'll check if it's the issue here.

Comment: @canton7 You were right. It's a threadpool starvation issue. Edited the question. Thank you. Post it as an answer so I can mark the question as answered. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think your explanation makes sense: threading new `Threads` shouldn't affect the `ThreadPool`.