# Syncing Timer to Screen Refresh Rate in .NET MAUI? Why is this timer not keeping up?

Tags: c#, animation, timer, maui, ticker

I would like to create a global timer in .NET MAUI that synchronizes to the screen refresh rate. The purpose is to allow me to run my custom UI animations off of it by subscribing their update functions to the global timer `Tick` event. The timer could also calculate `deltaTime` between its updates by comparing `DateTime.Now` at each `Tick`.

I have written it as:

```
 public class GlobalTicker {

     //delta time solver:
     public float deltaTime = 0f;
     DateTime deltaTimeDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

     //app run time:
     public float appRunTime = 0f;

     //UPDATE TIMER;
     public IDispatcherTimer timer;

     //SCREEN MONITOR:
     private float refreshRate = 120f;

     public GlobalTicker() {

         //get init screen info:
         refreshRate = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.RefreshRate;

         //make timer
         timer = Application.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer(); 
         timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / refreshRate); //run every 1/120 seconds or 1/60 seconds or so depending on refresh rate
         timer.IsRepeating = true;
         timer.Tick += (s, e) => tickPassed();
         timer.Start();

     }

     public void tickPassed() {
         MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

             deltaTime = (float)(DateTime.UtcNow - deltaTimeDateTime).TotalSeconds;
             appRunTime += deltaTime;
             deltaTimeDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

             Debug.WriteLine("TICK RATE " + 1 / deltaTime + " REFRESH RATE " + refreshRate + " TIMER INTERVAL RATE " + 1f / timer.Interval.TotalSeconds);

         });
     }
}
```

I stored the timer in the default Maui project `MainPage.xaml.cs` file as:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {

    public GlobalTicker globalTicker;

    public MainPage() {

        globalTicker = new();
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

This seems logical to me, but I am getting Debug output in this otherwise empty default project like this:

```
TICK RATE 31.140133 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 29.039968 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 31.953068 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 53.155014 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 32.066185 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 29.648605 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 31.816835 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 53.06053 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 31.891823 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 32.210476 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
TICK RATE 46.126526 REFRESH RATE 59 TIMER INTERVAL RATE 59.00018290056698
```

In other words, the tick rate is no where near synchronized to the refresh rate. The timer Interval rate and refresh rate are being read and set as ~59 both the same. But I'm only getting ticks at 29-53 fps with broad variation.

The CPU strain in the project is virtually zero as it is an empty project. How might I get a proper timer update synchronized to the refresh rate? What is the reason it is not synchronizing now?

Thanks for any help.

***EDIT***

Found this that might solve it - method for high resolution timer: [Most accurate timer in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228313/most-accurate-timer-in-net/31612770)

Comment: Where do you believe you are synchronizing with the vertical sync?  You're just setting up a periodic timer for 16ms.  Windows is not a real-time operating system.  When you ask for a timer at an interval, Windows merely guarantees that your delay will be **at least** as long as you requested.  And remember that you're using Invoke to switch back to the main thread -- that requires a context switch, which takes a variable amount of time.

Comment: Oh I see Tim. Thanks. I didn't know that. Is there any way to get a recurring event that occurs every `1/refreshRate` on a consistent basis in MAUI? If there is any code you can provide to illustrate or ideas for how to build it I'd appreciate it. And I think this Timer runs on main thread completely due to `Application.Current.Dispatcher` but either way I would like it running entirely on main thread as it is UI related exclusively. Thanks again for any thoughts.

Comment: You're right that the timer callback runs on the main thread.  Timer expirations in Windows are only examined at the scheduler interval, which is 16ms.  So, you can't get any more granular than that.  There ARE ways to literally get a callback on vertical sync, but you'd need to investigate the graphics APIs for that.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That's interesting. If you look through built in MAUI animations like `RotateTo` they seem to work by creating their on Ticker on running which runs at a max FPS of 60 or 120 and has its own Timer firing the update events for the tween. So that would suggest these built in animations would also be limited to ~60 fps. I am used to Unity where the entire application can be set to target the any rate (like 120 fps) and you can run functions consistently at that rate. I wonder how they do it. I didn't know it was so hard in MAUI to get say a 120 fps event firing.

Comment: This is the wrong tool for the wrong idea.

Comment: In what way H.A.H.? The built in animations like RotateTo are running off a Ticker which is running off a Timer as well if you look at them. That is what I see. If so, what is wrong then? I would just like better time resolution (120 fps) and custom animations as well. This seems to work "Accurate Timer": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228313/most-accurate-timer-in-net/31612770