# Sampling frequency of timer in Windows Form doesn't add up with the amount of actually logged measurements

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

This is my first post on SO. Usually just lurking, which helps me a lot. But I can't solve this one and need your help! 
I have made a test program using Windows Forms. It contains two buttons (a start and a stop button). When the start button is clicked, for every ms (millisecond), a log-function is being called, which extracts some basic information (or so I thought). The test stops after 2 minutes, where the stop function is clicked. When the test has been running for 2 minutes, there are only 7789 measurements. The test doesn't add up - any ideas, why is this so? I've attached a screenshot of the code of the start and stop buttons. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGLcp.png)

```
//Start-button

private void button1_CLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TestInitiated = true;
     LogTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
     LogTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(stopwatch_tick);
     LogTimer.Enabled = true;
     LogTimer.Interval = 1;
     LogTimer.Start();
}

//STop-Button
private void button2_Click)object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TestInitiated = false;
     LogTimer.Stop();
     LogTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: The [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) doesn't have that resolution (see the Remarks section). Also, see [High resolution timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45097518/7444103)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms timers are accurate to 55 milliseconds, you need to use a System.Timers.Timer if you need more accuracy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is it possible to use System.Timers.Timer while keeping the GUI in WinForm?

Comment: @tigram10 See the [System.Timers.Timer.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject) property. Note that if you have some processing between Elapsed events that take more than the Interval time, the events will overlap and you may have race conditions (and/or re-entrancy) issues.